# Add style with css based menu website.web on .Net

Tags: jquery, .net, css, menu, sitemap

I am creating an application in visual studio, and I have my sitemap.web. Also, I have a menu which takes as its source the sitemap (by loading the headings and subheadings of the sitemap).

I want to have an elegant and lively style on my menu. Should I use Jquery, css, or is there another way to style labels sitemap?

```
products" description="Our title="Products" <siteMapNode url="~/Products.aspx">
```

How I can incorporate a good style to my menu based on the sitemap.web?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean with good style compared to what your menu looks like now. But i would say that CSS is the right way to go. And have a look at CSS selectors http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html .

You could use jQuery if you want some special effects on your menu . It all depends on what you are looking to do. But baseline i would say is pure CSS.

Comment: As animations and effects I can put my menu, considering that this basadado in a sitemap and that the labels are: <siteMapNode>, I know I can with css or jquery, but as applying the style??

Comment: So you question is not what technologies there are to style your menu, but how to apply CSS styles to it?